# Unsatisfied Link error while loading native library - no openSSL4Java in java.library.path

Tags: java, ssl, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I get this whenever I try to run my program :

> [org.apache.security.juice.provider.JDKMessageDigestOpenSSL] Unsatisfied Link error while loading native library.: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no openSSL4Java in java.library.path

I got some binaries from this website: https://www.openssl.org/source/.

My guess is that it isn't the correct library and I tried to search `openssl4java`, but nothing pops up.

Comment: You're using: http://incubator.apache.org/projects/juice.html which is effectively defunct, which is what's complaining about the library.

Comment: Usually the standard libraries will not work. You need the openssl4java native JNI libraries that adapt the OpenSSL API for Java. You may have to build them.